# for loop dataframe last row of a group

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I'm struggling with a for loop for a dataframe.
I want a function where I loop through a dataframe with object names and their properties.
Suggest the dataframe looks like this:

```
data = [['object 1', 'property 1'], ['object 1','property 11'], ['object 2', 'property 2'],['object 2','property 22'], ['object 3', 'property 3'],['object 3','property 33']]
```

I want to generate a string where the last row of each object doesn't contain a comma and all other rows don't.

```
def addProperties(objects):
    obj = objects
    for index, row in obj.iterrows():
        if row['label'] =! #last element
        string = row['label'] + row['attribuutLabel'] + ','
        else:
            string = row['label'] + row['attribuutLabel'] 
            return string
```

Output should be something like this:

```
string = 'object 1 property 1, property 11, property 111 object 2 property 2, property 22 property 3, property 33'
```

I'm quite new to python so don't know what the best way is to achieve this.
Can someone help out?

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified what the correct output would be for the example.

Comment: I've added this to the questions, thank you for the feedback